# Change Language in ModalDialog without reload

Tags: web-part, javascript, language

I´ve got the following issue:

I want to change the Language of a .aspx Page, the NewForm.aspx. Therefor I created a WebPart which was added to the NewForm.

```
<div>
<a href="" onclick="OnSelectionChange(1033);">
    <img alt="" src="..." />
</a>

<a href="" onclick="OnSelectionChange(1031);">
    <img alt="" src="..." />
</a>
</div>
```

Problem of all is, that the a-tag points to the List where the NewForm belongs to so that the dialog after click shows the list not the NewForm view. What I want is that the NewForm ModalDialog just "refresh" or "reload" and the language is set. Do I have to set the lijnk to the NewForm manually or is there another way?

Thanks for all effort!

Comment: I didn't really get your question... Why can't you point the a-tag directly to the New Form? And what you mean by "NewForm ModalDialog just "refresh" or "reload" and the language is set"?

Comment: Cause I have two diffrent content types with diffrent IDs and I cant take the standard everytime. I want to reload the actual URL without point to another site.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution ;-)

```
<div align="center">
<a id="linkGB" href="" onclick="OnSelectionChange(1033);">
    <img alt="English" src="..." />
</a>

<a id="linkGER" href="" onclick="OnSelectionChange(1031);">
    <img alt="Deutsch" src="..." />
</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#linkGB').attr("href", $(location).attr('href'));
        $('#linkGER').attr("href", $(location).attr('href'));
    });
</script> 
</div>
```